# Delta integration in 2D

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Let's assume we have an integration like this:

$$I = \int d^2x_1  \ d^2x_2 \ \delta^2  (x_1 + x_2 -p)  \ f(x_1) \ f(x_2) $$

For a simple 1D delta function we can use this simply:

$\int \delta ⁡(x-a)⁢\phi ⁡(x)⁢dx=\phi⁡(a)$

...............................................................

An Example:

Let's use  functions for  $f(x_1)$  and$f(x_2)$ :
$$I = \int d^2x_1  \ d^2x_2 \ \delta^2  (x_1 + x_2 -p)   \  \  e ^{-x_1^2  + x_2^2 } $$

How would I treat $\delta^2$??

According to the 1D properties of delta function $\int \delta ⁡(x-a)⁢\phi ⁡(x)⁢dx=\phi⁡(a)$, the integration is applicable, when $p = x_1 + x_2$, but I'm not sure how to deal with the 2D delta function in the integration and the $d^2 x_1,$  or $d^2 x_2$,term.

Comment: As written, you have an integration on $\Bbb{R}^4$. Is this what you want?

Comment: @NinadMunshi, I was not sure how to  answer your question so, I have written an example. The reason I said the 2D delta, because it had a square term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a remark about notations. To be sure not to make forbidden manipulations, it is advised to see the Dirac delta as a distribution or as a measure, and so, for example in dimension $1$, it is better to write
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi(x)\,\delta_a(\mathrm{d}x) = \langle \delta_a,\varphi\rangle = \varphi(a)
$$
(unless you really know what you are doing).

About $I$, what is meant with this kind of expression is the lineic measure on the set
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R^{2d}}} \varphi(x_1,x_2)\,\delta_{\{x_1+x_2=p\}}(\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi(x,p-x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
which in this particular case can be seen as a generalized Fubini theorem (since I am in some sense using first the one dimensional definition of the Dirac with variable $x_2$ and then integrating with respect to $x_1$), but one could exchange $\{x_1+x_2=p\}$ with more general set. In your case this yields
$$
I(p) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)\,f(p-x)\,\mathrm{d}x = (f*f)(p)
$$
which is just the convolution of $f$ with itself (this is sometimes called the autocorrelation).

---

**Remarks:**

- Following my first remark about notations, notice that in particular, I wrote $\delta_{\{x_1+x_2=p\}}(\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2)$ what you call $\delta^2(x_1+x_2-p)dx_1dx_2$
- Other ways of writing the above formula for $I(p)$ that are perhaps more clear for the people not understanding the meaning of the first ones are
  $$
  \begin{align*}
  I(p) &= \int_{\mathbb{R^{2d}}} f(x_1)f(x_2)\,\delta_{\{x_1+x_2=p\}}(\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2)
  \\
  &= \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} f(p-x_2)f(x_2)\,\mathrm{d}x_2
  \\
  &= \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} f(x_1)f(p-x_1)\,\mathrm{d}x_1
  \end{align*}
  $$
  (but of course the name of the variable does not matter) or also by defining the space $S_p := \{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^{2d}, x_1+x_2=p\} = \{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^{2d}, x_1+x_2-p=0\}$ and defining $\mathrm{d}s$ as the uniform measure on this space
  $$
  \begin{align*}
  I(p) &= \int_{(x_1,x_2)\in S_p} f(x_1)f(x_2)\,\mathrm{d}s
  \end{align*}
  $$
- In the particular case of Guassians
  $$
  \begin{align*}
  I(p) &= \int_{\mathbb{R^{2d}}} e^{-|x_1|^2-|x_2|^2}\,\delta_{\{x_1+x_2=p\}}(\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2)
  \\
  &= \int_{\mathbb{R^{2d}}} e^{-|x_1|^2}\,e^{-|x_2|^2}\,\delta_{\{x_1+x_2=p\}}(\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2)
  \\
  &= \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} e^{-|x_1|^2}e^{-|p-x_1|^2}\,\mathrm{d}x_1
  \\
  &= (e^{-|x|^2} * e^{-|x|^2})(p)
  \\
  &= \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{d/2} e^{-|p|^2/2}
  \end{align*}
  $$
- In some sense, the Dirac Delta removes one integral, so in dimension one no integral are left, in dimension $2$ we pass from $2$ to $1$ integral.

Comment: Did you mean $\delta(_1+_2-)$ instead of $\delta^2 (_1+_2-)$

Comment: Yes, the notation is usually the same in every dimension. $\delta^2$ could be confused with the square of the distribution, which has no meaning!

Comment: And the same is true whatever the dimension of $x_1$ and $x_2$. I put a general dimension $d$, since it seems in your case $x_1\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Tell me if there is anything else you do not understand.

Comment: What would be the result of the example integral I gave?  I still have some confusion intuitively. I may get your answer, and ask you the question if  you work on the example with your methods.  Thanks :)

Comment: Did you wanted to write $e^{-(|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2)}$? Then just replace $f$ by $e^{-|x|^2}$, where is the problem? If your question is then to compute what is the convolution product of two Gaussians, then this is a different question (please do never modify questions)

Comment: In the particular case of Gaussian functions, the convolution product is also a Gaussian function. If $x∈\mathbb{R}^d$, then
$$
e^{-|x|^2} * e^{-|x|^2} = \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{d/2} e^{-|x|^2/2}
$$

Comment: I have one question. How the modified question is different than the original one? I just used the  example functions   $f(x) f(y) = e^{-x_1^2} e^{-x_2^2}$. And we have to  integrate them with respect to   to $d x_1^2 dx_2^2$ right? And also, i guess it is not mentioned that $x_1 = x_2$, so how would you treat the $\delta^2 (x_1 + x_2 -p)$

Comment: Please let me know, i can write a new question if you think I should do so. :)

Comment: No, no need to open a new question if what bothers you is still the definition of $\delta(x_1+x_2-p)$ (I thought you wanted to know also the convolution of two gaussians). So it seems you just do not understand my answer, then please read more carefully, **I am not telling that $x_1=x_2$**, I am telling that by definition, when you integrate with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$ in an integral with $\delta_{x_1+x_2=p}(dx)$ (or $\delta^2(x_1+x_2-p)$ in your notations), **then you have only one integral remaining in which $x_1+x_2 = p$**. I can for example call $x = x_1$ and then $x_2=p-x$.

Comment: I added more remarks.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating it.  I understand it now.